# compare if date from database is bigger than current date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, session

I'm stuck on this one.

It sounds quite easy what I'm trying to accomplish, still I can't get it to work...

I have several user stored in a database. They can visit a page after login. But each user has an end date. So if this day has passed, he won't be able to see the page anymore and will be redirected to another page. But there is a different date for each user.

When an user enter his credentials, a $_SESSION is created that stores his login name. I need the sql to get the date from the specific user using this $_SESSION value.

What I have so far:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE licentiehouder=$naamLicentiehouder";
$naamLicentiehouder = $_SESSION['doorsturen'];
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$mydate = $row['vervaldatum'];
$curdate=strtotime("now");

if($curdate <= $mydate && $_SESSION['doorsturen'] == 'userONE') {
header("Location: userONE.php");
} else if ($curdate <= $mydate && $_SESSION['doorsturen'] == 'userTWO') {
header("Location: userTWO.php");
} else if($curdate > $mydate) {
header("Location: extend_license.php");
}
```

So again, every user has it's own license, which will expire on an exact date. This date is stored in the database. So if userONE's logging in, $_SESSION value is set to userONE. sql reads this values and gets only the row that's matching this value. If today (current date) is bigger than the date stored (so his license is expired), he will be redirected to a page to extend his license. If not, he will be able to see his personal page.

Hope anyone can help?!

Comment: `$curdate` seems to be a UNIX timestamp. What type is `$mydate` ? Is it a mysql date datatype ? Please `echo` the contents of `$mydate`

Comment: $curdate is a varchar

Comment: changed it to date, doesn't make a difference. It just echoes errors. The echo displays nothing

Comment: store dates as date types, this will make life a lot easer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable `$naamLicentiehouder` is undefined at the time you run your query. Try:

```
$naamLicentiehouder = $_SESSION['doorsturen'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE licentiehouder='$naamLicentiehouder'";
```

Also `mysql_query()`, and the like, are depreciated. Use `mysqli`. I prefer the Object Oriented approach, since it saves a lot of repetitive typing.

To clarify, the Object Oriented approach, on a separate `restricted` page we'll call `connect.php`:

```
<?php
// reusable db() function can be called inside other functions
function db(){
  return new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');
}
?>
```

Now on your other page:

```
<?php
include_once 'restricted/connect.php'; $db = db();
if($db->connect_error)die("Connection Failure: {$db->connect_error}");
$naamLicentiehouder = $_SESSION['doorsturen']; // I would shorted this variable
if($result = $db->query("SELECT vervaldatum FROM your_table_name WHERE licentiehouder='$naamLicentiehouder'")){
  if($result->num_rows > 0){
    $row = $result->fetch_object(); $mydate = $row->vervaldatum;
    $curdate = strtotime('now');
    if($curdate <= $mydate && $naamLicentiehouder === 'userONE'){
      header('LOCATION: userONE.php'); die;
    }
    elseif($curdate <= $mydate && $naamLicentiehouder === 'userTWO'){
      header('LOCATION: userTWO.php'); die;
    }
    elseif($curdate > $mydate){
      header('LOCATION: extend_license.php'); die;
    }
    else{
      die('Date Issue.');
    }
  }
  else{
    die('No results were found.');
  }
}
else{
  die('Error :'.$db->error);
}
$result->free(); $db->close();
```

Comment: Usually you create a connection on a separate secure page, using `$db = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database')`. Then you would type `$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE licentiehouder={$_SESSION['doorsturen']}");`. Hold on I'll make clear.

Comment: @JeffreyvanZwam How can you get `mysqli_` warnings when your code only uses `mysql_`

Comment: At first I tried your code, this resulted in a "no results were found" warning on the screen. So I've added the session_start on top of the screen. Now it redirects to the extend_license.php all the time, no difference if I change the date from the database to tomorrow or to last week, it still opens extend_license.php

Comment: I changed the code, instead of redirecting to exted_license.php I echoed both $curdate and $mydate on the screen. $curdate gives a result, $mydate doesn't. That declares why the code always redirects to extend_license, $mydate is 0, so the $curdate is always bigger.

Comment: Has to do with the way the date is initially entered into the database. Show database structure and `INSERT` code.

Comment: Database holds just 3 types; id (INT, A_I, primary), licentiehouder (VARCHAR 999), vervaldatum (date). I changed vervaldatum from DATE to DATETIME to TIMESTAMP to VARCHAR, neither one of them is giving me a result. The date is entered manually into the database, because I don't have s script yet that enters the values. I need to get this script working before I continue.

Comment: I changed the code `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(vervaldatum) FROM your_table_name` to `SELECT * FROM your_table_name` and this works fine, exactly as I want it to!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be getting a timestamp with `$curdate=strtotime("now");` What you are getting from the database is likely (although I can't be sure) a date, not a timestamp. Use strtotime on it too:

```
$mydate = strtotime($row['vervaldatum']);
```

That should do it.

Comment: I also tried to change the database from date to timestamp and even datetime, neither of them is giving a result